# Creating a Form Designer

Tags: html, form-designer

I was asked to create a Form Designer from my supervisor but, I do not know where to even begin. (And my supervisor didn't give me a good explanation).... :/

So from what I can gather, a Form Designer is basically a wizard that lets user pull a field and assign the field with appropriate values within the database, to create a "form".

How should I go about starting this? I'm quite new to software dev so that's maybe why I'm having hard time trying to start this form designer project.

Can this be done through Dreamweaver (HTML)?? Are there other alternative programming language that I can use to create it really quick and easy?

Thank you very much! Any kind of information about creating one, and others will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: You need more info.  Giving a complex project with ill-defined requirements to an inexperienced developer is a guarantee for failure.  It won't be your fault, but you'll probably get blamed anyway.

Comment: @Jason My supervisor said I got all the info I need.... all the variables are in the database (there are crap loads of them).... so I guess the main problem is how to start this project... I have no immediate help within where I work... so yeah.. I'm kinda effed. AND the best part... I have to get this done by the end of the month... which is just few days away.... and my supervisor assigned this yesterday. WTF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a form desginer is a great tool..

I work with symfony framework, is very cool. The framework has a form designer, not visual but you can choose the field type even has a many validators.

For more information visit the guide http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/. This guide is divided en chapters, the three first chapters can explained how to create a forms

I hope this is useful